# I need to check if first number of array equals to the last

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array

```
    const array = [[1, 2], [3, 3]]; arr.forEach(el => {  
      if (el[0] === el[1]) {return true}
    })
```

Comment: Please elaborate. What is the expected output for the given array? What doesn't work with the above code?

Comment: *Note:* Change `arr.forEach` to `array.forEach` .. Check for right spelling..

Comment: Yeah, thank you! I found it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should should `every` function

```js
const arr = [[1, 2], [3, 3]]; 
const b = arr.every(el => el[0] === el[1]);
console.log(b); // false
```

Comment: @Max please note that this will check that the start and end elements match for ALL array in your list of arrays.

Answer (score 1):

There is no point in return true in a forEach

I assume you mean this:

```js
const testArr = arr => arr[0] === arr[arr.length-1]; // test first and last

const array = [[1, 2], [3, 3]]; 

const testResults = array.map(el => testArr(el)); // map the results
console.log(testResults)

// filter: 

const same = array.filter(el => testArr(el)); // FIND the array that has same first and last 

console.log(same.flat())
```

Answer (score 1):

This should get the desired result. Just change console.log(true) to whatever you would like to do if they equal each other. This will work on any length of array.

```
const array = [
  [1, 2],
  [3, 3],
];

array.forEach((el) => {
  if (el[0] === el[el.length - 1]) {
    console.log(true);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

[`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) over the array to produce a new array of true/false values determined on whether the elements match.

```js
const out = [[1, 2], [3, 3]].map(arr => {  
  return arr[0] === arr[1];
});

console.log(out);
```